# Getting ora-00927 missing equal sign in Oracle SQL but I am showing all equal signs needed

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Here is the code.
I have checked multiple times over but everything looks in place.
Could i still be missing the equal sign or could it be some other matter?

```sql
MERGE INTO existing_customers c
USING new_customers n
ON (c.customer_id = n.customer_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    c.first_name = n.first_name,
    c.last_name = n.last_name,
    c.address_state = n.address_state,
    c.email_address = n.email_address,
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (c.customer_id,c.first_name,c.last_name,c.address_state,c.email_address)
    VALUES (n.customer_id,n.first_name,n.last_name,n.address_state,n.email_address)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the trailing comma after `n.email_address`?

Comment: Alternativelly add equal sign here: `WHEN = NOT`(this is the place Oracle complains) and you will get more intuitive error `ORA-00936: missing expression`